# JavaScript Date() differs when timezone changes

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I need to convert my date to `mm-dd-yyyy` format. So I used a method like this:

```
var dt=new Date(2016-06-21);

var ddte='';

ddte=(("0" + (dt.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2))+"-"+(("0" + dt.getDate()).slice(-2))+"-"+dt.getFullYear();
```

It works fine in my local timezone (`GMT+05:30`). But when I change my timezone to `GMT -5:00`, it gives the wrong result: `06-20-2016`. The result I want is `06-21-2016`.

1. Can anyone please explain the problem?
2. How can I get the correct result?
3. Is it a bug?

Comment: var dt =new Date('2016-06-21'); instead of Date(2016-06-21).Single quote missing.

Comment: How are you changing your timezone?

Comment: Why it is a bug? Probably in that timezone is current day.

Comment: Well, that's how time zones actually work. It isn't the same calendar day everywhere at the same time.

Comment: But i just want the date to be converted to the desired format and be displayed..Is it really dependent on the timezone??I could not understand!!

Comment: I input the the date and i expect the same date to get as the result

Comment: This is a duplicate that has been answered many times. The simple solution is don't use a Date, just reformat the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date passed to `Date()` constructor will be treated as UTC time zone. Getting the time with `Date.getMonth()` will get your local time zone. You're probably looking for  `Date.getUTCMonth()`.

```js
var dt=new Date("2016-06-21");

var ddte='';

ddte=(("0" + (dt.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2))+"-"+(("0" + dt.getUTCDate()).slice(-2))+"-"+dt.getUTCFullYear();

console.log(ddte);
```

Though in this case I see no use for using `Date` at all; this should suffice:

```js
var parsedDate = "2016-06-21".replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/, "$2-$3-$1");
console.log(parsedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a bug. It's just how time zones work (it isn't the same calendar day everywhere in the world at the same time).

If you don't actually want advanced date features (it seems you only want some good old string manipulation) my tip is to just not use `Date` in the first place.

```
var parts = "2016-06-21".split("-");
var mdy = parts[1] + "-" + parts[2] + "-" + parts[0];
```

Add some error checking and you're done.

Comment: @RobG Don't worry, I probably pissed someone in some other question. I've had some weird downvotes since yesterday.